# Activate Joomla account with a purchase

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I would like to have an account in Joomla and have a custom field called "paid" then have the user pay money to set this field to true. I can make a [profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) and then use PHP to do the MySQL check for the field and then serve the file. But how can I make the users pay money to change this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people want a free solution, but if you're willing to pay a small fee for a GREAT component, I'd highly recommend [Membership Pro](http://joomdonation.com/joomla-extensions/membership-pro-joomla-membership-subscription.html).  We use several of their components and they're among our favorites to work with.

Comment: I would like more of a pay to get an account not a subscription based thing. I was hoping this would be an easy task with PayPal but I guess not.

Comment: That's pretty much what the component does...they pay for a "membership", at which time you can assign any user group to them.  Paypal can be used to pay, and you *can*, but don't have to configure all sorts of extra fields for the user.  It's exactly what you're asking for.